# How is "おらず" used in the following sentence?

Tags: translation, verbs, honorifics

I'm trying to read a short story whose theme (*I think?*) is that in order to have self-awareness other people are necessary. Like, they act as abstract mirrors to view oneself (or something...). So, I totally do not understand the usage of "**おる**" in the following sentence:

> 自分一人だけで立っては**おらず**、他人がいて初めて自己という存在が認識できる。

So, I roughly diagram the sentence:

> (**おらず**) being all by yourself, it is from the existence of other people that one begins to have self-recognition.

ok. So, "おる" is the humble form of "いる".

<1> While I am almost sure you **cannot** say "いず" for "居る", you **can** say "おらず" for "おる"?
<2> What is the meaning of that "おらず"? How do you translate the entire sentence?
<3> This is an objective philosophical essay. Why are honorifics used at all?

thank you.

Comment: Why do you think you can't say いず? And おる is sometimes used simply to sound loftier than いる.

Comment: I think "いず" has 3 steps: (1) to exist, (2) to not exist, (3) to begin existing again. That doesn't make sense. But, I'm sure "いず" is correct grammar.

Comment: いず is basically a more formal way to say いなくて or いないで. I'm not sure what you mean by those steps.

Comment: @Nothingatall What I was trying to say, and still sort of believe: "飛ばずに" means (1) it must have the potential to fly, (2) when it "飛ばずに" it commits to not flying, but only for a period of time, (3) after the "飛ばずに" period is over, it once again has the potential to fly. "飛ばなくて" has no sense of a time period. But.... I'm very wrong because my understanding does not allow for the idea of "いず".

Comment: I can't find a source, but I don't think there's any humbleness implied by おる here; I think it's just used because おらず is a nicer form than いず. Along these same lines, I've also seen ～ており used as the 連用形 of ～ている.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<1> Yes, いず does not sound natural in this context.
<2> 立ってはおらず has the same meaning as 立っているのではなくて
<3> It does sound more formal, but the nuance does not really change.

I would loosely translate it like this:

> It's not that you are alone; a sense of self-awareness first comes from being surrounded by others.